# Why does checking whether a hashset has added as a boolean return false

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, hashset

I hope my question was worded correctly.. here is a snippet of code, if I uncomment the line `System.out.println(hs.add(ar));` console will print true, so why are reaching inside the following if statement?

```
public static void duplicateExists(String [] array)
{
    Set<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String ar : array)
    {
//          System.out.println(hs.add(ar));
            if((hs.add(ar)) == false);
            {
                System.out.println("reaches here every time but shouldn't ");
            }
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        duplicateExists(new String[] {"1","2","5","3","6","8"});
}
```

Comment: `if((hs.add(ar)) == false);` Delete the semicolon.

Comment: can't believe i didn't notice that, thought I was going mad, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if((hs.add(ar)) == false);
```

Does nothing, because of the **ending semicolon**. The element is actually added to the set, despite the condition of the `if` is never satisfied.

Then, you have the following block of code:

```
{
    System.out.println("reaches here every time but shouldn't ");
}
```

It's awkward, but in Java, you can have arbitrary blocks of code surrounded by braces. This one is always executed, because (due to the semicolon) is totally independent of the previous `if`.

Try removing the semicolon:

```
if ((hs.add(ar)) == false) {
    System.out.println("reaches here every time but shouldn't");
}
```

Formatting the code might be seen as something not very important, but here is a case that clearly shows that when code is not nicely formatted, unintuitive, unexpected, hard-to-debug issues might happen.

Besides, you could simplify your code:

```
if (!hs.add(ar)) {
    System.out.println("reaches here every time but shouldn't");
}
```

Now it doesn't reach the `println`.